# equality doesnt work with php

Tags: php

I am trying to check two sentences in greek equal with this function:

```
   private function process_line_three($target_line_three,$case_line_three){
      $target_line_three=trim($target_line_three);
       $case_line_three=trim($case_line_three);
      echo "<br/><br/>";
       var_dump($case_line_three);
        echo "<br/><br/>";
        echo mb_detect_encoding($target_line_three);
        echo "<br/><br/>";
         echo mb_detect_encoding($case_line_three);
       //$this->print_chars_not_equal($target_line_three,$case_line_three);

   return strcasecmp($target_line_three, $case_line_three)==0;
   }
```

When I pass them the following two strings I get this:

```
Line 3: case Συνδέσου με χιλιάδες ανθρώπους Παρακολούθησε & δράσε ζωντανά 24/7==Συνδέσου με χιλιάδες ανθρώπους Παρακολούθησε & δράσε ζωντανά 24/7
```

But equality fails here.. i return false on that result, even though both sentences are similar.. why is that so?

**UPDATE :**

> var_dump($case_line_three); string(117) "Συνδέσου με χιλιάδες
>   ανθρώπους Παρακολούθησε & δράσε ζωντανά 24/7"

meanwhile, i am trying to find an encoding issue

**UPDATE 2:**
the output is:

```
string(117) "Συνδέσου με χιλιάδες ανθρώπους Παρακολούθησε & δράσε ζωντανά 24/7"
```

> UTF-8
>
> UTF-8

both characters are utf

**UPDATE 3**
output when I write to a file:

```
Συνδέσου με χιλιάδες ανθρώπους Παρακολούθησε &amp; δράσε ζωντανά 24/7

Συνδέσου με χιλιάδες ανθρώπους Παρακολούθησε & δράσε ζωντανά 24/7
```

Comment: You are working with UTF-8, [right](http://webcollab.sourceforge.net/unicode.html)?

Comment: Try using var_dump() rather than echo to display the two values

Comment: use mb string compare as characters are not normal

Comment: it returns 1, and i guess its true.

Comment: The characters you are reporting are equal visually. We don't know what the function process_line_three() does. At this point I'm suspecting that the culprit is the ampersand (&). Do a var_dump() as @Mark Baker suggested

Comment: what should vardump do.. I did it on case_line_three .. see update

Comment: Ok, are you able to write just the two strings to a file, say f.txt, and, on a Unix/Linux shell type `od -tx1z f.txt`?

Comment: yeah, i could write them both to a file.. i will do so now

Comment: thanks.. i used this: htmlspecialchars-decode() to get rid of the amp

Comment: you should rather use `htmlspecialchars()` more often...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `strncmp` to compare the two strings character for character, stopping when they are not equal. Then you could determine which character(s) is different. `levenshtein` might tell you how many characters are different.

```
$a = 'Συνδέσου με χιλιάδες ανθρώπους Παρακολούθησε & δράσε ζωντανά 24/7';
$b = 'Συνδέσου με χιλιάδες ανθρώπους Παρακολούθησε & δράσε ζωντανά 24/7';

$i=1; $l=strlen($a); $equals=true;
while ($i<=$l && $equals) {
    if (strncmp($a, $b, $i) != 0) {
        $equals = false;
    } else {
        $i++;
    }
}
if ($equals) {
    echo 'Strings are equal';
} else {
    echo 'Character '.$i.' is not equal';
}
```

Strings are equal for me, so it is probably an encoding issue. You could use `mb-detect-encoding` to check the encoding of the offending characters http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: that is a potential solution thanks..i will try it now.. all should be utf.. i take the data from my database.. it has collation of utf8_unicode_ci  and i also set all my queries to being utf

Comment: This is a horrible solution, since it does nothing but reimplement `strcmp()`.

Comment: @Niko `strcmp` won't tell you which is the offending character, so I used `strncmp`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
if(strcmp ($target1 , $target2 ) == 0);
```

A second alternative will be using a multibyte encoding insensitive comparison....

```
function mb_strcasecmp($target1, $target2, $encoding = null) {
    if (null === $encoding) { $encoding = mb_internal_encoding(); }
    return strcmp(mb_strtoupper($target1, $encoding), mb_strtoupper($target2, $encoding)); }
```

Comment: Are you doing this on a local server? What OS is the PHP server running on?

Comment: Well, you already solved the problem, but the second option should work nevertheless... just recheck your code

Answer (score 1):

Try to use PHP native method `strcasecmp()` - http://php.net/strcasecmp .

Comment: strcasecmp() is not multibyte safe

Answer (score -2):

Could there be an encoding problem?

Try using this:

```
return (strcmp($target_line_three, $case_line_three) == 0);
```

`strcmp()` is case-sensitive. For case insensitive, use `strcasecmp()`

Comment: Call to undefined function strcomp()

Comment: it returns me this as true: Δες webcam δωμάτια =E= Ζωντανά webcam chat rooms | Gr.ImLive.com Result: 2

Comment: There is no function called `strcomp`. You probably mean `strcmp`.

Comment: sorry, it's strcmp(), not strcomp()

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd They are equal if strcmp() or strcasecmp() returns exactly 0 - `return (strcasecmp($target_line_three, $case_line_three) === 0);`